# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in

Tags: php, mysql

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
$sentencia=$conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usu_usuario=? AND usu_password=? AND usu_token=?");
$sentencia->bind_param('ss',$usu_usuario,$usu_password,$usu_token);
$sentencia->execute();
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Intenta responder qué estas intentando hacer? Dónde? Qué esperas obtener y que obtienes? Para que tu pregunta pueda interpretarse, debes dar mas contexto a los lectores. Estaría bueno que revisaras [Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Tambien recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: @BetaM. Sólo formatee el código; la traducción ya estaba hecha.

Answer (score -1):

En **bind_param** tan sólo declaras 2 String, pero estás mandando 3.

```
bind_param('ss',$usu_usuario,$usu_password,$usu_token);
```

Debería ser:

```
bind_param('sss',$usu_usuario,$usu_password,$usu_token);
```